# How do I connect a client to an IdentityNode with two managers?

Tags: chisel, rocket-chip

The PCIe overlay I'm attempting to invoke connects the two slave/manager nodes to a slaveSide IdentityNode like so:

```scala
  val slaveSide = TLIdentityNode()
  pcie.crossTLIn(pcie.slave)   := slaveSide
  pcie.crossTLIn(pcie.control) := slaveSide
```

How do I connect my client to both of these nodes? Would it be something like this?

```
slaveSide :*= myClient
```

What if I wanted one client for each manager?  Is there a way outside of changing the overlay placing function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following worked for this situation.

```
// Assuming TLClient1 and TLClient2 have been declared. 

val connectorNode = TLIdentityNode()

connectorNode := TLClient1
connectorNode := TLClient2

slaveSide :=* connectorNode
```

Since here the number of slaves and clients is equal

```
slaveSide :*= connectorNode
```

should be equally as valid.